# redux-form Field with AutoComplete using redux-form-material-ui

Tags: material-ui, redux-form

I am working on a AutoComplete Field in redux-form and found this solution. Thought this will help someone using material-ui or redux-form-material-ui and looking to get rid of `muiTheme` errors. For my case I found it simple using react-select.

```
{/* Libraries you need */}

import {AutoComplete as MUIAutoComplete} from 'material-ui'
import { AutoComplete } from 'redux-form-material-ui'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import { reduxForm, Field, Fields, formValueSelector, change } from 'redux-form'


{/* redux-form Field component for Text Input using AutoComplete */}

<MuiThemeProvider>
   <Field
    name="searchByText"
    label="Search Suggestions"
    component={AutoComplete}
    floatingLabelText="Search By Suggestions"
    openOnFocus
    filter={MUIAutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}
    dataSource={searchSuggestionList}        //array list of suggestions
    onChange={this.handleSearchByTextChange} //handle the onChange event by handleSearchByTextChange func
    onBlur={() => {}}
  />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: Usually when you use redux-form-material-ui library with the redux-form field. Like I used for Autocomplete dropdown suggestions and text field. It will throw error stating muiTheme isRequired. Which is set to be required in {AutoComplete} of material-ui library. For this, I wrapped the field with MuiThemeProvider as you see in the code. This will provide a default muTheme for material-ui.
 
Later the scope of the project that I was working is changed, so I used react-select instead. But provided this solution here, so that someone interested can look into it.